# Replace column using awk

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have 3 files

1file

```
 14/09/15
 14/09/15
 14/09/15
 14/09/15
 14/09/15
```

2file

```
14/09/01 
14/09/01
14/09/01
14/09/01
14/09/01
```

and 3file

```
15/09/14,11-37,01/09/14,1224A,0G,71%,RGS
15/09/14,11-41,01/09/14,2700A,0G,94%,RAN
15/09/14,11-43,01/09/14,2701A,0G,100%,RAN
15/09/14,11-44,01/09/14,2701B,0G,92%,RAN
15/09/14,11-46,01/09/14,2708A,0G,88%,RAN
```

I need replace the column 1 from 3f with the column 1 from 1f and the third from 3f with the column 1 of 2f

How can I replace using awk?

Comment: i tried awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$3;next}{$1=a[FNR]}1 a awk like this but dont work, thanks for the suport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following awk code will be usefull

```
$ awk   'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}NF==1{line[FNR]=line[FNR]","$0} NF>1{split(line[FNR], a); $1=a[2]; $2=a[3]; print $0}' 1file 2file 3file
14/09/15,14/09/01,01/09/14,1224A,0G,71%,RGS
14/09/15,14/09/01,01/09/14,2700A,0G,94%,RAN
14/09/15,14/09/01,01/09/14,2701A,0G,100%,RAN
14/09/15,14/09/01,01/09/14,2701B,0G,92%,RAN
14/09/15,14/09/01,01/09/14,2708A,0G,88%,RAN
```

**What it does??**

- `OFS=FS=","` sets output field separator`OFS` and field separator `FS` as `,`
- `NF==1{line[FNR]=line[FNR]","$0}` If number of fields/columsn , `NF` is one, save the value in `line` variable seperated by commas
- `NF>1{split(line[FNR], a); $1=a[2]; $2=a[3]; print $0}` takes the action when `NF` greater than one

  - `split(line[FNR], a);` split the `line` variable to array `a`
  - `$1=a[2]; $2=a[3];` sets the first and second column
  - `print $0` prints the entire record